# Vanilla JavaScript replace element

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, replacewith

I've looked around and can't seem to find a solution to directly replacing an element with a HTML string using vanilla JavaScript (not jQuery).

I'm storing a bunch of svg's in a directory that's publicly accessible, and I want to be able to include them in my files via the image tag `<img src="path/to/svgs/example.svg">`.  However, this comes with its drawbacks as they can't be coloured/styled when they're pulled in as an image (to my knowledgE).

I discovered this example [jQuery Image to SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement) but obviously this uses jQuery's `replaceWith` function. I'm trying to replicate the functionality but struggling with the aforementioned function. All examples I've found end up creating a parent `div` element, and appending the new HTML to that newly created element.

TL;DR: Can I directly replace an element (IMG to SVG) using vanilla JavaScript without creating parent nodes?

Comment: Could you show us an example of code that you currently have and an example of desired result? Something like [mcve]

Comment: It's worth noting that jQuery [does this by creating a temporary parent node](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/src/manipulation/buildFragment.js#L41); what's the reason for your prohibition against doing the same?

Comment: Are you willing to use `<svg><use xlink:href="example.svg"/></svg>` instead of an `<img>` tag? Would something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51664058/179125) work for you?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is also using JavaScript behind replaceWith method, so if you want to replace one element with another you need to do next steps:

1. Create new element
2. Add it after/before an element that needs to be replaced
3. Then remove original element

**e.g**
If we have HTML list

```
<ul>
        <li>before</li>
        <li id="my-element">My element</li>
        <li>after</li>
    </ul>
```

and we want to replace list item, with id "my-element", with the new element then we need to do **next**:

```
//get reference to element that we want to replace
var elementToReplace = document.getElementById('my-element');
//create new element which will replace existing element
var newLi = document.createElement('li');
//just setting html in it
newLi.innerHTML = 'Just added';
//getting parent element reference and executing method "insertBefore" passing our new element and reference of element that we want to replace
elementToReplace.parentNode.insertBefore(newLi, elementToReplace.nextSibling);
//then we remove original element
elementToReplace.parentNode.removeChild(elementToReplace);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already loaded the SVG into a string (via `XmlHttpRequest`, `fetch` etc). Then you can parse it using the `DOMParser`.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingSVGSource, "image/svg+xml");
```

See: [Parse SVG and add it to a svg element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273908/parse-svg-and-add-it-to-a-svg-element)

Then you can replace the original `<img>` using something like the `insertBefore`/`removeChild` method that Senad suggests.